# SVN files on remote updated but not being part of repo

Tags: svn

I think I am going crazy. I have a dev set up on my local, where I work and I commit my work as I go. Then, when it is finished, I go to my server, where svn is installed, and I do svn up. I know this is not the best way to do it.

Anyway, I worked yesterday on some changes I was not ready to deploy until today (I had to run some SQL queries before the code goes live). I received a message from an user the production app was not working. I checked and it seemed the code reached production.

I entered to the terminal on my server and I checked the svn log, but the latest commits were not there. However, the files I have been adding and my changes were there!

I can't comprend or understand what happened. Even when I tried to do svn up it failed because the files already existed. I had to delete all the universioned files and then do the svn up.

How this happened? I can't find a reason. I think I am going crazy. Does this happened before to someone else or a similar case?

Comment: It sounds like somehow you transferred the files to your server outside Subversion. Perhaps you had a drive mapped to it and were saving the files there and didn't realize it, or had an open ssh/terminal/remote desktop connection and were working live on the server?

Comment: Yeah, that was the obvious first attempt but nope. Not FTP, no remote desktop, etc. It could be that when I commit with Tortoise it triggered some kind of update in all the external repos? I know it sounds impossible, but I cant think of anything else.